# Problem in implementing two search filters in react table

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, react-table

I am implementing a table in react and I want to search data in tables based on two factors, i.e., Filter-By-Name and Filter-By-Consultant. You can see the expected output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD7Iu.png)

Now the problem is that I have implemented Search-By-Name successfully and it works fine. Now I coded the Search-By-consultant but I don't know how to call it in the table body along with Search-By-Name.

Here is my **Bookings.js**. I Know I have to call FilteredConsultants in the table body along with FilteredNames but how to do that?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../static/Bookings.css';
import {BsFilterRight} from "react-icons/bs";

const Bookings= ()=>{
    const[Bookings, setBooking]=useState([]);
    const[searchByName, setSearchByName]=useState('');
    const[FilteredNames, setFilteredNames]=useState([]);
    const[searchByConsultant, setSearchByConsultant]=useState('');
    const[FilteredConsultants, setFilteredConsultants]=useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        loadUsers();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setFilteredNames(
            Bookings.filter(Booking=>{
                return Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchByName.toLowerCase())
            })
        )
    }, [searchByName, Bookings]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setFilteredConsultants(
            Bookings.filter(Booking=>{
                return Booking.consultant.toLowerCase().includes(searchByConsultant.toLowerCase())
            })
        )
    }, [searchByConsultant, Bookings]);

    const loadUsers= async()=>{
        const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Bookings");
        setBooking(result.data.reverse());
    };

    const deleteUser=async id => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/Bookings/${id}`);
        loadUsers();
    }

    return(
        <div className="Booking-page-container">
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Bookings Page</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped border shadow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">
                        <BsFilterRight/>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="search by name..."
                                onChange={e=>setSearchByName(e.target.value)}
                            />  
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                        <BsFilterRight/>
                            <input 
                                placeholder="search by consultant..."
                                onChange={e=>setSearchByConsultant(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
          
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consultant</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {FilteredNames.map((Booking,index)=>(
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
                            <td>{Booking.name}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.consultant}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.email}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link class="btn btn-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/view/${Booking.id}`}>View</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/edit/${Booking.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>deleteUser(Booking.id)}>Delete</Link>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bookings;
```

Comment: Are your filters supposed to be an OR or AND condition? In other words, if someone enters a name and consultant does a booking have to have that name and the consultant to be displayed?

Comment: It should be AND based

Comment: If I enter a name and consutant then I want to see the table rows that satisfies both the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, once `searchByConsultant` or `searchByName` is changed Table is displaying Bookings filtered by only one of the values.

It you would like to filter with 'and' condition, then you would need to construct filter using both of values.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setFilteredNames(
      Bookings.filter(Booking=> {
        const byName = !searchByName || Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchByName.toLowerCase());
        const byConsultant = !searchByConsultant || Booking.consultant.toLowerCase().includes(searchByConsultant.toLowerCase());
        return byName && byConsultant;
      })
  )
}, [searchByName, searchByConsultant, Bookings]);
```

+ `FilteredConsultants` seems that isn't really used here